# How to further filter on a query's .Include(.Where()) and have it reflected outside of the Include()

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, ef-core-5.0

I understand that my question is kind of confusing because I haven't found a better way to ask it, but I'm sure it isn't a hard problem to solve.

Here's what's happening:

I'm supposed to return a `List<Place>` inside a method called `GetAllPlaces` in the entity's repository.

Place entity:

```
public Guid PlaceId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public Point Location { get; set; }
public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
public List<Hour> Hours { get; set; }
```

Hour entity:

```
public Guid HourId { get; set; }
public Guid DayOfTheWeekId { get; set; }
public DayOfTheWeek DayOfTheWeek { get; set; }
public DateTime OpenHour { get; set; }
public DateTime CloseHour { get; set; }
public Guid PlaceId { get; set; }
public Place Place { get; set; }
```

Each `Place` have a `List<Hour>` property. I'm trying to filter on this list of hours to not return places that are closed to the caller of this method.
What I have so far is that I'm filtering to only include the Place's today's Hour in the Place's timezone:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Place>>
            GetAllPlacesAsync(
            double lat,
            double lon
            string userCity,
            double visibleRadius)
        {    
            var geometryFactory =
            NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
        var userLocation = geometryFactory
            .CreatePoint(new Coordinate(lon, lat));

            var places = await context.Places
                .AsNoTracking()

                .Include(s => s.Hours
                    // here I'm filtering to get just today's Hour like explained previously
                    .Where(d => d.DayOfTheWeek.DayName
                        == TimeZoneInfo
                        .ConvertTime(DateTime.Now,
                            TimeZoneInfo
                            .FindSystemTimeZoneById(d.Place.Timezone.Name))
                            .DayOfWeek
                            .ToString()).FirstOrDefault())
                // a second .Where() would filter on the .Include()
                // or on the "places" List but not on its Hours.
                // How to further filter to do something like this:
                // if Place.Hour.Open <= timeNowInPlaceTimezone
                // && Place.Hour.Close >= timeNowInPlaceTimezone ? passToList : dontPassToList

                .Where(
            x => x.Address.City == userCity
            && x.Location.IsWithinDistance(userLocation, visibleRadius))
                .Distinct()
                .ToListAsync();

            return places;
        }
```

Do you know how I could filter it to only get the places where the `Hour` of the place is between the open and close hour of today in its timezone ?

**EDIT 1**

So, thanks to @TN's answers, here's the SQL I wrote:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateIsOpenAndSelectForMap
@UserLat DOUBLE PRECISION,
@UserLon DOUBLE PRECISION,
@PlaceLat DOUBLE PRECISION,
@PlaceLon DOUBLE PRECISION,
@UserCity NVARCHAR(100),
@VisibleRadius DOUBLE PRECISION,
@PlaceToUserDistance DOUBLE PRECISION,
@UserLocation GEOGRAPHY,
@PlaceLocation GEOGRAPHY
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SRID INT;
SET @SRID = 4326; -- in meters

-- Create geolocation for the user's location and the Place's location
-- as well as the distance between the user and the Place in order
-- to then return the places where the distance between the two
-- is smaller than the visible radius.
SET @UserLocation = geography::Point(@UserLat, @UserLon, @SRID);
SET @PlaceLocation = geography::Point(@PlaceLat, @PlaceLon, @SRID);
SET @PlaceToUserDistance = @UserLocation.STDistance(@PlaceLocation)

-- TO DO
-- create the new table PlacePinOnMap

-- Update the IsOpen property
UPDATE [P]
SET [IsOpen] = [OpenTimeCalc].[IsOpen]

-- when the user runs this stored procedure and updates the IsOpen
-- property, it returns a "new table" with the updated data
-- to be put into a DTO in the code.
OUTPUT [P].[PlaceId],
       [P].[Location],
       [P].[Latitude],
       [P].[Longitude],
       INSERTED.[P].[IsOpen],
       [M].[Name],
       [E].[EC]

FROM [Places] [P]
JOIN [Timezones] [TZ] ON [TZ].[TimezoneId] = [P].[TimezoneId]
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Get the Place's timezone's local datetime
    SELECT
        GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE [TZ].[Name] AS [LocalDateTime]
) [LT]
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Get the Place's timezone's local week-day name and local time
    SELECT
        DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [LT].[LocalDateTime]) AS [LocalWeekdayName],
        CAST([LT].[LocalDateTime] AS [TIME]) AS [LocalTime]
) [DT]
CROSS APPLY (
    -- Get the event count of event that are in the future
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
        FROM [E]
        WHERE [E].[Date] >= [LT].[LocalDateTime]
) [EC]
JOIN [DaysOfTheWeek] [DOW] ON [DOW].[DayName] = [DT].[LocalWeekdayName]
JOIN [Moods] AS [M] ON [P].[MoodId] = [M].[MoodId]
-- Also wanted to get the events related to the place
JOIN [Events] AS [E] ON [P].[PlaceId] = [E].[PlaceId]
CROSS APPLY (
    -- select place where its open and closed hours are within
    -- the ones of the local time, for the day returned from the local datetime
    SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [StoreHours] [SH]
        WHERE [SH].[PlaceId] = [P].[PlaceId]
        AND [SH].[DayOfTheWeekId] = [DOW].[DayOfTheWeekId]
        AND [SH].[OpenHour] <= [DT].[LocalTime]
        -- special case where closing time of '24:00' is stored as '00:00',
        -- since time does not support '24:00'
        AND [SH].[CloseHour] > [DT].[LocalTime] OR [SH].[CloseHour] = '00:00'
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsOpen]
) [OpenTimeCalc]
WHERE ([P].[IsOpen] <> [OpenTimeCalc].[IsOpen])
AND ([P].[Address].[City] = @UserCity)
AND (@PlaceToUserDistance <= @VisibleRadius);

END
```

Comment: Note that the tagging guidelines state that you should not put tags in your question title.

Comment: Will remove them

Comment: You should avoid calling `ToListAsync()` and instead return `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn do you have an article or something I could read to understand it further ? Thank you

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @Jimmy In a nutshell, `ToList()` and `ToListAsync()` force the server to load the entire result set into memory at the same time. Returning the `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` (which is what you have if you don't call `ToList()`) allows you do process one record at a time, which can be **HUGE** for memory use and performance generally. It also allows you do continue to compose and build the query from the calling code, which can be helpful.

Comment: @NetMage LINQ to SQL using EF Core 5.0.11

Comment: @NetMage recent would be > EF Core 5 ?

Comment: Yes, EF Core >= 5 supports filtered `Include` so it should be possible.

Comment: Thank you @JoelCoehoorn ! I look more into it so learn because I needed performance improvements

Comment: @NetMage I did filter the Include but I don't think it was what I was looking for, it seems like I should be using a `.Where()`

Comment: Are Places and Hours database-hosted collections (tables)?  If so, what DBMS are you using, what version, and what are the database data types used for storing Place.Timezone and Hours.DayOfTheWeek?

Comment: Please add DayOfTheWeek, Timezone and Place.Timezone to your posted data structure, and also add a tag for your DBMS (sql-server or some other).

Comment: I would be interested in knowing what gets generated on the SQL side. Is the database provider able to convert the entire query (including time zone calculations) into native SQL or does it just run a query to retrieve all Place rows and then perform all of the filtering on the C# side (or something in the middle). If the latter, just be aware of the cost. You might want to consider converting the entire query into a native SQL Server query in a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I forgot about the fact that it would generate SQL, you're right, I wouldn't want server side calculations for something like this. I'll run a test and see what gets generated and I'll post it. Besides that, do you know which of the two ways would be better in terms of performance if let's say SQL can run the conversion natively ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, most releases of Entity Framework do not support translation of time zone functions, but it appears that EF Core 7.0 add support for `EF.Functions.AtTimeZone()` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#support-for-at-time-zone) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.attimezone?view=efcore-7.0). For older versions of EF, you may need a SQL-only solution for which I have posted a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, it may be better to perform all of the filtering on the database  side using native SQL to convert the date/times and apply the open/close criteria. This would avoid loading the entire Place table and likely the entire StoreHours table into the C# environment with every execution.

The stored procedure would look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOpenPlaces
AS
    SELECT P.*
    FROM Place P
    JOIN Timezone TZ ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Intermediate local time calculations
        SELECT
            GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE TZ.Name AS LocalDateTime
    ) LT
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- More intermediate local time calculations
        SELECT
            DATENAME(weekday, LT.LocalDateTime) AS LocalWeekdayName,
            CAST(LT.LocalDateTime AS TIME) AS LocalTime
    ) DT
    JOIN DayOfTheWeek DOW ON DOW.DayName = DT.LocalWeekdayName
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM StoreHour H
        WHERE H.PlaceId = P.PlaceId
        AND H.DayOfTheWeekId = DOW.DayOfTheWeekId
        AND H.OpenHour <= DT.LocalTime
        AND (H.CloseHour > DT.LocalTime OR H.CloseHour = '00:00')
    )
```

The above supports a special case where a closing time of '24:00' is stored as '00:00', since time does not support '24:00'

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PL_jjeAk) for a demo that includes a variety of generated test data and a slightly modified version of the query above for illustration purposes.

This all assumes that your time zone names match those known to SQL Server. I believe that SQL server time zone information and .Net TimeZoneInfo are both based off if operating system registry data, this should be a valid assumption as long as updates are regularly applied.

Also, I recommend that you define an index on `StoreHour(PlaceId)` as a minimum, or (better) `StoreHour(PlaceId, DayOfTheWeekId, OpenHour, CloseHour)`.

Comment: First off, thank you for putting such effort in helping me. Thank you so much you don't know how much this helps. Besides that, this is getting hard for me to understand haha raw SQL isn't something I'm familiar with and I looked up your db fiddle link and even though I get the general idea it's still hard to understand. Therefore I'm going to watch and read about a bunch of SQL courses and I'll be right back, it should only take a day or two.

Comment: Also I have a question, if I want to update the `IsOpen` property of the `Place` entity within the query. Should I do it like the second way I've posted with the `foreach` loop or should it be included in the raw SQL as a field `Update` ? Because I've read that I should update the property for each `Place` and call `SaveChanges` once at the end, and I can't do it any other way in the query

Comment: @Jimmy - First I would question the need for a column in the table that you would need to constantly update over time. If that requirement is non-negotiable, I recommend doing this using another stored procedure containing much of the same code to calculate the current IsOpen status (see fiddle), but combined with an UPDATE statement that sets the new value if the calculated value differs from the prior stored value. The statement would look something like `UPDATE P SET IsOpen = O.IsOpen FROM Place P JOIN Timezone TZ ... CROSS APPLY (SELECT ... AS IsOpen) O WHERE P.IsOpen <> O.IsOpen`.

Comment: Here is an [updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w4AH6-R5).  As you look through SQL tutorials, I hope that you will file the `SELECT` list, `FROM` and `JOIN ... ON ...` clauses, and the `WHERE` conditions fairly straight-forward.  Many of the function calls like `DATENAME()` and `CAST(value AS type)` are pretty specific to SQL, as is the very unique `date-time AT TIME ZONE timezone-name` syntax.  The `CROSS APPLY (...)` is much less common, but one of its uses is to introduce intermediate calculations as I have done in my queries to avoid duplication of expressions. Good luck.

Comment: An alternative to the stored procedure is to code the SQL up as a single multi-line C# string and then pass it in as raw SQL to Entity Framework for execution. The frequently running IsOpen update SQL may also be a candidate to for execution as a SQL Server Agent job, either as plain SQL or by scheduling the EXEC stored procedure statement.

Comment: Alright, so I posted the result of the query, and as you said it failed, I don't really understand what I'm reading but it says that it can't convert the timezone or that it can't map the method inside of the statement. So I think I'll have to use your custom SQL, while I learn more to be able to understand what you've written in SQL, can you please review the error message and confirm that you were right ? Thank you so much

Comment: In short, the database provider only supports a finite number of operators and commonly used functions when converting C# `IQueriable<>` expressions into native SQL. However, ` TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById()` is not one of them. It might be possible to refactor your logic to use the recently defined `EF.Functions.AtTimeZone()`, but I have no experience with this. Converting the LINQ query to an `IEnumerable<>` by tossing in a `.AsEnumerable()` might work, but would read everything into memory before applying the filter logic. I think native SQL is your only remaining alternative.

Comment: Thank you, after learning some SQL I'll read your db fiddle thoroughly, make sure I understand it all and then try your code with the data in my DB, and post the result. Logically we'll get the data needed to know how to make this work and then make it an answer

Comment: Hi @TN, I read a bunch of SQL courses and I wrote the script I believe could work for my needs, thanks to you I can finally code in SQL for the things I need. Could you take a look at it on the post ? I shortened the post to just have that SQL so that it's easy for you to read it. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

First just to clarify my understanding or your data: Each place has a `List<Hour>` collection where each `Hour` object has properties `DayOfTheWeek`, `Open`, and `Close` - similar to a line item on a [store hours sign](https://www.google.com/search?q=store+hours+sign&tbm=isch). Also, each `place` has an associated timezone to which the current (UTC) date/time needs to be converted before checking against the `place.Hours` collection.

I do not believe `.Include()` is what you want here, since that function is for selecting extra data to be eagerly loaded with the result rather than to filter the result.

My expectation is that you want something like `.Where(place => place.Hours.Any(hour => hours-matches-local-time)`.

However, the `hours-matches-local-time` part may include complex calculations that may be unnecessarily evaluated inside the `.Any()` multiple times for the same place. To avoid redundant calculations, the condition in the outer `.Where()` can be made into a code block where the local day-of-week and local-time are calculated once per place, assigned to variables, and then referenced repeatedly inside the inner `.Any()`.

Try something like:

```
var places = await context.Places
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(place => {
        var localDateTime = ...;
        var dayOfWeekInPlaceTimezone = ...;
        var timeNowInPlaceTimezone  = ...;
        bool isOpen = place.Hours
            .Any(hour =>
                hour.DayOfTheWeek == dayOfWeekInPlaceTimezone
                && hour.Open <= timeNowInPlaceTimezone
                && hour.Close > timeNowInPlaceTimezone
            );
        return isOpen;
    })
    //(not needed) .Distinct() 
    .ToListAsync();
```

The above uses *LINQ Method syntax*. An alternative is to use the *LINQ Query syntax* which can also calculate local variables using the `let` clause. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251075/declare-variable-within-linq-selectx-new) has answers that demonstrate some of those techniques. (Perhaps someone with more experience than I in LINQ query syntax can post a translation.)

There may be other opportunities for improvement, such as grouping places by timezone and calculating local day/time once per group. A `.SelectMany()` would eventually be used to process each group and flatten out the results. The result might be something like:

```
var places = await context.Places
    .AsNoTracking()
    .GroupBy(place => place.Timezone)
    .SelectMany(tzGroup => {
        var timezone = tzGroup.Key;
        var localDateTime = ...;
        var dayOfWeekInPlaceTimezone = ...;
        var timeNowInPlaceTimezone = ...;
        return tzGroup.Where(place =>
            place.Hours.Any(hour =>
                hour.DayOfTheWeek == dayOfWeekInPlaceTimezone
                && hour.Open <= timeNowInPlaceTimezone
                && hour.Close > timeNowInPlaceTimezone
            )
        );
    })
    //(not needed) .Distinct() 
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `var` inside `Queryable.Where`? Anyway, proposing loading whole table is not a good solution.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I don't know if there is a way to write `TimeZone` (or `TimeZoneInfo`) calculations in a LINQ query that can be translated into native SQL by the database provider.  The alternative might be to convert everything into a stored procedure. and use perhaps SQL `DateTimeOffset` or `AT TIME ZONE` conversion capabilities.

Comment: (Sidenote: Anyone who takes on the task of doing date/time arithmetic across time zones should watch this cautionary video first - [The Problem with Time & Timezones - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).)

Comment: I tried to do it but it gives me an error before I can even test it and says `a lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree`, do you know what I should do ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv "loading whole table is not a good solution" do you mean it's better to use a `.Select()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your condition about Open/Close hours, but query should look like this:

```cs
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Place>>  GetAllPlacesAsync()
{    
    var dayOfWeek = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo .FindSystemTimeZoneById(d.Place.Timezone.Name))
        .DayOfWeek
        .ToString();

    var places = await context.Places
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(p => p.Hours.Any(h =>
                h.DayOfTheWeek.DayName == dayOfWeek 
                && h.Open <= timeNowInPlaceTimezone
                && h.Close >= timeNowInPlaceTimezone
            )
        )
        .ToListAsync();

    return places;
}
```

Comment: I see, but I need to create `timeNowInPlaceTimezone` and `dayOfWeek` within the `places` query because I need each `Place` to pass its `Id` for the `dayOfWeek` and `timeNowInPlaceTimezone` that's what I don't know how to do. Also, `.Any()` will return a bool right ? will that add the `Place` to the list if it returns true and not if it returns false ? And what type should the `passToList` be ?

Comment: Which EF Core version do you use and which Data Provider?

Comment: EF Core 5.0.11 and Sql Server

Comment: Open, Close, why not store as `integer` in minutes?

Comment: How do you mean ?

Comment: The problem is that for each place, the solution needs to access place.Timezone, calculate the current day-of-week/time for that timezone, and then apply those results as filters against hours. I don't think the timezone logic can be coded in a C# expression tree in a way that can be translated to native SQL. Either the filtering needs to be done on the C# side (inefficient, as it reads the entire Places & Hours tables into memory) or this will need to be coded up as a SQL-only solution, such as a stored procedure. The latter would use SQL-server native timezone operations.